# How to parse a line for an email address in perl using regular expression?

Tags: string, perl, parsing, email-address

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to parse an Email Address out of a string using a RegEx.

I dont think I can use the Email::Address module, as it did not come with the perl version we were told to download, else this would be quite simple.

My current code with the Email::Address

```
use strict;

#use Email::Valid;

my $infile = 'IJCA_reviewer_list.txt';
my $outfile = 'output.txt';
open my $out, ">> $outfile";
open my $in, "< $infile" or die "Can't open $infile : $!";
use Email::Address;

while(my $line = <$in> ) {

    chomp $line;

    my $addrs = Email::Address->parse($line);

    print $out "$addrs , ";
}

close $in;
close $out;
```

Comment: A lot of things are a lot simpler if you can use CPAN http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html show a regex for parsing emails.

The specification for emails is pretty harsh.

You probably be best off to search cpan for a module that will
split up the email into parts for you.

Comment: You could try installing Email::Address locally.

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSlurp) and [Email::Address](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aAddress) like this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp qw( read_file );
use Email::Address;

my $infile  = 'IJCA_reviewer_list.txt';
my $outfile = 'output.txt';

my $intext = File::Slurp::read_file( $infile );
my @emails = Email::Address->parse( $intext );

File::Slurp::write_file( $outfile, join("\n", @emails) );
```

**UPDATE**: If you need help installing CPAN modules, you can read [this](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).